# Get Master Sound Volume in C++ in Windows XP

Tags: c++, audio, windows-xp, volume

On Windows Vista and later it is posible to get master sound volume with MMDevice Api:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnum = NULL;
IMMDevice *pDevice = NULL;
IAudioMeterInformation *pMeter = NULL;
float peak;

HRESULT hr;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator),     
                      NULL,
                      CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                      __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
                      (void**)&pEnum);

hr = pEnum -> GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);

pDevice -> Activate(__uuidof(IAudioMeterInformation), 
                    CLSCTX_ALL,
                    NULL,
                    (void**)&pMeter);

pMeter -> GetPeakValue(&peak); // I need this value
```

But how to get this info on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN, [Peak Meters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the audio endpoint device implements the peak meter in hardware, the IAudioMeterInformation interface uses the hardware peak meter. Otherwise, the interface implements the peak meter in software.

Before Vista, there was no hardware peak metering on devices or KMixer (predecessor to WASAPI for internal audio mixing). There was no software fallback implementation to provide metering data too. So you just don't have the data, you cannot obtain it.

If you have the data you send to playback, you might want to implement software metering over this data feed.

Comment: How about `mixerGetControlDetails` ?

Comment: What MSDN section about it made you think it could be helpful?

Comment: `mixerGetControlDetails()` assign a value to the `dwValue` member of `MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED` structure. Will it contain the current speaker volume?

Comment: I'd say there is a chance it can, you need to dump all mixer data it makes available and find it out. Firstly it anyway depends on actual capabilities your driver has, not the full range of features including optional that documentation advertises.